# Checking the linear dependence of vectors which are some linear combinations of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ and the set $S=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$. Now consider the set of some linear combinations $T=\{v_i=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{ij}u_j: i=1,2,...,n\}$ of vectors in $S$, How to justify that $T$ is linearly independent if and only if the matrix $A=[c_{ij}]$ is invertible?

I have seen some where (anecdotal) that the matrix equation $\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \vdots\\
v_n\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}c_{11}&c_{12}& \cdots &c_{1n}\\c_{21}&c_{22}&\cdots&c_{2n}\\ \vdots&&&\\
c_{n1}&c_{n2}& \cdots&c_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\ \vdots\\
u_n\end{pmatrix}, $ ensures the equivalence ''$T$ is linearly independent if and only if the matrix $A$ is invertible''. But I couldnot connect the result as I am confused about about the operation in the right hand side since $A$ is a matrix with scalar entries while $\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\ \vdots\\
u_n\end{pmatrix}$ is a matrix with vectors $u_i$.

Can we generalize the equivalence for any vector spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for some not all zero $x_1,\dots, x_n$ there holds
$$
\sum_i x_i v_i = 0.
$$
Then,
$$
\sum_{i,j} x_i c_{ij}u_j = 0.
$$
Set
$$
b_j = \sum_i x_i c_{ij} = (A^Tx)_j
$$
and observe that
$$
\sum_{i,j} b_j u_j = 0.
$$
Since $S$ is linearly independent, the $b_j$'s are all 0. So x is in the null space of $A^T$ which implies that $A^T$ (equivalently A) is not invertible.

The converse is obtained by reversing the argument.